# Android RecyclerView item width in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, fragment

I have a `RecyclerView` that gets inflated in a `Fragment`. The problem is, when the items count gets more than views height, every item that is in the view will get a width of highest content (I mean all will get wrap content of highest width). In the image it's more specific, also after scrolling those views that will get refreshed will have a correct width (match parent). I already have tried those code suggestions on other questions but still problem exists. here is my code:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.complex_item, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

The xml layout for items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/baseBg"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/expand_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/list_item_background"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center|right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPage5"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code snippet that does the fragment replace:

```
mainPageFrameLayout.removeAllViews();
FragmentTransaction ft = 
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.mainPageFrameLayout, new MojtamaFragment(id, "3"));
ft.commit();
```

And the `mainPageFrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainPageFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPage5" />
```

The adapter and the `onCreateView`:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_fragment, container, false);

    final RecyclerView recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    ...
    //(this part items is getting generated by a Http Request)
    ...
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(recyclerView, id, title, getActivity(), complexID,MojtamaFragment.this));
    return rootView;
}
```

Images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit: Image explanation: as you can see in image 1 when items numbers gets more than views height items width gets wrap_content instead of match_parent (Image 2 is the correct one that it should be) in image 3 as you can see after i did scroll, items that get's re-instantiated gets correct width. I hope you get the point.

Edit 3: This is whole adapter and viewholder code and imports:

```
package com.ahrabi.ojekavir.Fragments;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ahrabi.ojekavir.R;
import com.ahrabi.ojekavir.connector.HttpVolley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by Ahrabi2 on 1/10/2018.
 */

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class MojtamaFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String GET_COMPLEX_LIST_URL = "/Building/getComplexList";
    public static final String LOGIN_URL = "/user/Login";

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    public String firsturl;
    private String[] id, title;
    private String idCame, complexID;

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public MojtamaFragment(String id, String complexID) {
        this.idCame = id;
        this.complexID = complexID;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_fragment, container, false);

        final RecyclerView recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));


        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        if (prefs.getBoolean("net_switch", false)) {
            // Your switch is on
            Log.v("Requests", "Over Network");
            firsturl = prefs.getString("internet_url", getResources().getString(R.string.pref_default_display_internet));
            Log.v("Over internet url", firsturl);
        } else {
            // Your switch is off
            Log.v("Requests", "Over Local");
            firsturl = prefs.getString("local_url", getResources().getString(R.string.pref_default_display_local));
            Log.v("Local url", firsturl);
        }
        String[] keys = new String[2];
        String[] values = new String[2];

        keys[0] = "ComplexTypeId";
        keys[1] = "regionID";

        values[0] = complexID;
        values[1] = idCame;


        new HttpVolley
                ().HttpVolleyPost(getActivity(), firsturl + GET_COMPLEX_LIST_URL, keys, values, new HttpVolley.VolleyResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(String message) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (response.contentEquals("-7")) {

                } else {
//                        response = response.replaceAll("\\", "");
                    Log.v("Response", response);
                    String jsonResult = "{" + "\"" + "android" + "\"" + ":" + response
                            + "}";
                    try {

                        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonResult);

                        // Getting JSON Array from URL
                        JSONArray android = jObject.getJSONArray("android");
                        Log.v("android", android.toString());
                        Log.v("android.length()", "" + android.length());
                        id = new String[android.length()];
                        title = new String[android.length()];
                        for (int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);
                            // Storing JSON item in a Variable
                            id[i] = c.getString("id");
                            title[i] = c.getString("Name");
                        }
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(recyclerView, id, title, getActivity(), complexID,MojtamaFragment.this));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        });
        return rootView;
    }

    private void showLoginPopup(String page) {
        LayoutInflater curInflate = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View curLayout = curInflate.inflate(R.layout.login_popup,
                (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainLinearPopup));

        final PopupWindow swindo = new PopupWindow(curLayout,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, true);
        swindo.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

        swindo.setFocusable(true);
//      swindo.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupWindowAnimation);
        swindo.showAtLocation(curLayout, Gravity.BOTTOM,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        LinearLayout bg = (LinearLayout) curLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.bgLinearPopup);
        LinearLayout loginIV = (LinearLayout) curLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.loginIV);
        final EditText loginUserName = (EditText) curLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.loginUserName);
        final EditText loginPassword = (EditText) curLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        if (page.contentEquals("1"))
            loginIV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.item_brown_bg);
        else if (page.contentEquals("3"))
            loginIV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.item_orange_bg);
        bg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                swindo.dismiss();
            }
        });
        loginIV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (loginUserName.getText().toString().contentEquals("")){

                } else if (loginPassword.getText().toString().contentEquals("")){
                } else {
                    String[] keys = new String[2];
                    String[] values = new String[2];

                    keys[0] = "userName";
                    keys[1] = "password";

                    values[0] = loginUserName.getText().toString();
                    values[1] = loginPassword.getText().toString();



                    new HttpVolley
                            ().HttpVolleyPost(getActivity(), firsturl + LOGIN_URL, keys, values, new HttpVolley.VolleyResponseListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError(String message) {


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            if (response.contentEquals("1")) {

                            } else {

                            }
                        }

                    });
                }

            }
        });
    }
    private static class SimpleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleAdapter.ViewHolder> {


        private RecyclerView recyclerView;

        private String[] id, title;
        private Context context;
        private String complexID;
        private MojtamaFragment mojtamaFragment;
        public SimpleAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView, String[] id, String[] title, Context context, String complexID,MojtamaFragment mojtamaFragment) {
            this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
            this.context = context;
            this.complexID = complexID;
            this.mojtamaFragment = mojtamaFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.complex_item, parent, false);

            return new ViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {


            holder.textViewTitle.setText(title[position]);
            if (complexID.contentEquals("1"))
                holder.textViewTitle.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPage6));
            else if (complexID.contentEquals("3"))
                holder.textViewTitle.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPage5));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return id.length;
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

            private TextView textViewTitle;
            private LinearLayout expandButton;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                expandButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expand_button);
                textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);

                expandButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            }


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(getAdapterPosition());

                mojtamaFragment.showLoginPopup(complexID);

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide more code, like your xml layout and your adapter

Comment: Please explain the images a little to understand your problem. The problem is not quite clear.

Comment: as you can see in image 1 when items numbers gets more than views height items width gets wrap_content instead of match_parent (Image 2 is the correct one that it should be) in image 3 as you can see after i did scroll, items that get's re-instantiated gets correct width. I hope you get the point.

Comment: Please add whole adapter code with Imports

Comment: could you share the adapter and viewholder code ?

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much editing and experiencing i found a part of code from my xml layout (the one that FrameLayout is in it and fragment gets replaced by it) has something to do with error:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.ahrabi.ojekavir.CityActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_city">
```

after removing app:layout_behavior and changing ContraintLayout to some Linear or RelativeLayout problem now is gone.

I don't know why this part raises such problem, but it has definitely a reason.